# Cast to generic type causing ArrayStoreException in Java

Tags: java, arrays, generics, casting, arraystoreexception

I am making a class that contains an instance variable of type `Object[]` that is named `array`. This class includes a method that returns a `T[]`, where `T` is a generic. The method should copy the contents of `array` on to the array to be returned. The relevant code looks like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
T[] arr = (T[])Array.newInstance(a.getClass(), array.length);
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    T temp = (T)array[i];
    arr[i] = temp;
}
return arr;
```

In the above snippet, `a` is yet another array that was passed as a parameter.

The issue is, when I call the method, it throws an `ArrayStoreException`. I'm not sure why it is doing that because I am casting the initial value to type `T` before storing it in the array which is of type `T[]`, so the types match. Why is is still throwing the exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With that code you create an `T[][]` because `a.getClass()` is `Class<T[]>`.

What you want is `a.getClass().getComponentType()`, thats the actual `Class<T>`

So:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
T[] arr = (T[])Array.newInstance(a.getClass().getComponentType(), array.length);
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    T temp = (T)array[i];
    arr[i] = temp;
}
return arr;
```

Or you can use the jre method

```
Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length); // creates a new array and copies the content
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to check the relationship between the type of `array[i]` and `T`, because they don't necessarily have an extended relationship.